# MySQL insert into (conditionally selected table) in single statement

Tags: mysql

My dbm knowledge is still pretty limited, so I am not sure how to approach/solve this problem. I want to `INSERT INTO` one of two tables, say, table1 and table2, but I don't know which table until after a `SELECT` subquery. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT tblname) SELECT *, IF(somecondition, 'table1', 'table2') as tblname FROM `anothertable` WHERE id = 'someid'
```

I tried this as a test:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT tblname) SELECT *, 'table1' as tblname FROM `anothertable` WHERE id = 'someid'
```

But that didn't work.

I know I can use subqueries in `SELECT` statements (so useful!), and that I can technically achieve what I want with `NOT EXISTS` in 2 statements, and I know I *cannot* `INSERT` into two tables, and I know that using @ user variables is unreliable within a statement ([see docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)). So, is there a way to achieve what I want, *in a single statement*?

Comment: I don't think so outside of the single stmt being a call to a stored proc. There are conditional joins, but not conditional tables afaik

Comment: Don't forget you can always concat your way into any Prepared Stmt like the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/38295132

Answer (score 2):

you can do it  with case statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( SELECT  IF(somecondition, 'table1', 'table2') as tblname FROM `anothertable` = 'table1' )
    THEN <QUERY A>
    ELSE <QUERY B>
END
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, and variations of it, and nothing seems to work.